# Issues with Depth (returning no callbacks) during multiple repeat restarts of App

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am having issues with the Depth callbacks (in Unity) consistently populating with data. It seems somewhat random as I start and stop and restart my application.   I'm utilizing the Pose (position) updates as well as the Depth updates.  (For the "RoomScanner for Project Tango" app on the play store)

Is there a recommended way to be "closing" or "killing" the apps within the Unity C# code that will produce better/more consistent behaviour with the Depth stack?

I'm getting "bad" returns approximately 60% of the time I run/launch my app for the Depth data, though the Pose data is happy.  I've made great progress with my code, but am very hesitant to publish this version to the play store with it being so unstable.

Suggestions? Did I miss something in the Unity/Tango Walkthroughs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a regression in the unitypackage, it has been fixed. Try download and re-import the package again.

Answer (score 0):

are you using an area definition file ?  If so, if the environment doesn't match, pose stops returning results - the callback is fine, you just aren't getting any - see this question [Tango Pose Pair Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037542/why-doesnt-onposeavailable-allow-multiple-pair-base-types)